# How to use butterknife in my case?

Tags: android

In my code, how should i change if i want use butterknife?

Layout list_item is listview, so I can generate butterknife injection, but I don't know how to fix other code, should I use ViewHolder?

```
public class GangAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Gang> {


public GangAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Gang> gangs) {
    super(context, 0, gangs);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    Gang currentFeature = getItem(position);


    ImageView spotImageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.Image);
    spotImageView.setImageResource(currentFeature.getImageResourceId());

    TextView featureTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.where);
    featureTextView.setText(currentFeature.getFeature());

    TextView detailTextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.about);
    detailTextView.setText(currentFeature.getExplanation());

    return convertView;
}
```

Here is my list_item.xml.
I think there is no problem. isn't it?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/where"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left" />
```

Comment: Why don't you use DataBinding with adapter. It's much better and you can set bind Gang properties to ImageView and TextView inside xml file.

Comment: @Thracian Databinding... interesting, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup the annotations and the pass the inflated view to while binding as

```
public class GangAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Gang> {

    @BindView(R.id.Image) ImageView spotImageView;
    @BindView(R.id.where) TextView featureTextView ;
    @BindView(R.id.about) TextView detailTextView ;
    //^^^^^^^^^^^ do the setup

    public GangAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Gang> gangs) {
        super(context, 0, gangs);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, convertView);
            //                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
            // pass the view with which you want to bind the views
        }

        Gang currentFeature = getItem(position);


        spotImageView.setImageResource(currentFeature.getImageResourceId());

        featureTextView.setText(currentFeature.getFeature());

        detailTextView.setText(currentFeature.getExplanation());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code, but I got the error from logcat 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference'

Comment: @youngban post your layout `R.layout.list_item` though make sure you have the right id's

Comment: I posted, is there any problem..?

Comment: only one it should be `R.id.image` instead of `Image` and make sure you have not-null data, if data is not null then try it by removing if condition , though should work with the current suggestion